# Is there any way to avoid having the browser's address changed after using "render"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently following the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). And there is something that has been bugging me for quite some time. I looked it up but I still can't find a good answer.

Anyway, I've noticed is when you have a validation error in the signup page it renders the original signup page and changes the nav bar address. I've matched **/signup** to the  action **new**, but if I use **render** it changes from **/signup** to **/users** (the default, because of the RESTful standard I guess).

I'll leave some lines of my code:

routes.rb

```
 resources :users
 match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'
```

users_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      @user.password = ""
      @user.password_confirmation = ""
      render 'new'
    end  
  end
```

So I've tried to work around this by not using the **render** method but **redirect_to** instead but I'm having trouble using it. As it is actually sending data to the path provided, @user.errors gets overwritten by creating a new instance of the model and the flash variable cannot show the errors.

_errors.html.erb

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2>
            <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>
            prohibited the user from being saved:
        </h2>
        <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
        <ul>
            <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

My question is: is there any way that by using **render** I can change the url displayed on the navbar? It's really frustrating if someone makes a mistake in the signup form, presses enter in the navbar and ends up in a totally different place.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the address changes is because you have performed a POST request to **/users/** therefore the browser is doing the correct thing by displaying the different address.

There are a few of ways around this:

1. Store the invalid User object and redirect back to the Users.new action.
2. Change the URL of the Users.create action.
3. Use history.replaceState to change the user's address bar.

The first option keeps the controller more RESTful, however it will need use of the :session or flash to persist the data across the redirect.

The second option keeps the code simpler, but involves fiddling with the **routes.rb** file.

The third option relies on javascript and support for HTML5 to mess with the user's browser history.

Personally I would leave the URL as is, but if I had a client who insisted on doing this, I would go for the second option.